# How to retrieve SecurityContext in a Quarkus application?

Tags: java, security, jax-rs, quarkus

I have a Quarkus application in which I implemented the `ContainerRequestFilter` interface to save a header from incoming requests:

```
@PreMatching
public class SecurityFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
   private static final String HEADER_EMAIL = "HD-Email";

   @Override
   public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
       String email = requestContext.getHeaders().getFirst(HEADER_EMAIL);

       if (email == null) {
           throw new AuthenticationFailedException("Email header is required");
       }

       requestContext.setSecurityContext(new SecurityContext() {
           @Override
           public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
               return () -> email;
           }

           @Override
           public boolean isUserInRole(String role) {
               return false;
           }

           @Override
           public boolean isSecure() {
               return false;
           }

           @Override
           public String getAuthenticationScheme() {
               return null;
           }
       });
   }
}
```

In a class annotated with `ApplicationScoped` I injected the context as follows:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ProjectService {
    @Context
    SecurityContext context;
    ...
}
```

The problem is that the `context` attribute is actually never injected, as it is always `null`.

What am I doing wrong? What should I do to be able to retrieve the `SecurityContext` throughout the application's code?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I like to abstract this problem, so that the business logic does not depend on JAX-RS-specific constructs. So, I create a class to describe my user, say `User`, and another interface, the `AuthenticationContext`, that holds the current user and any other authentication-related information I need, e.g.:

```java
public interface AuthenticationContext {
    User getCurrentUser();
}
```

I create a `RequestScoped` implementation of this class, that also has the relevant setter(s):

```java
@RequestScoped
public class AuthenticationContextImpl implements AuthenticationContext {
    private User user;

    @Override
    public User getCurrentUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setCurrentUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

Now, I inject this bean and the JAX-RS `SecurityContext` in a filter, that knows how to create the `User` and set it into my application-specific `AuthenticationContext`:

```java
@PreMatching
public class SecurityFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Inject AuthenticationContextImpl authCtx; // Injecting the implementation,
                                               // not the interface!!!

    @Context SecurityContext securityCtx;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        User user = ...// translate the securityCtx into a User
        authCtx.setCurrentUser(user);
    }
}
```

And then, any business bean that needs the user data, injects the environment-neutral, application-specific `AuthenticationContext`.

Comment: Thanks! This really did it!

Comment: It just throws AuthenticationContext is null for me i am injecting `AuthenticationContextImpl` in method argument

Comment: I tried this, but my SecurityFilter is never called. The doc sais you have to add a `@Provider` annotion, but this also didn't help...

Comment: My feeling for the two comments above is that they belong to a different question - i.e. why Quarkus is not injecting a SecurityFilter/why Quarkus is not invoking a SecurityFilter. I would try to isolate the problem and make sure I have a setup that actually injects and invokes the SecurityFilter, before proceeding to this solution.

Answer (score 2):

`@Context` can only be used in JAX-RS classes - i.e. classes annotated with `@Path`.

In your case, `ProjectService` is a CDI bean, not a JAX-RS class.

The canonical way to do what you want is to inject the `SecurityContext` into a JAX-RS resource and then pass that as a method parameter to your `ProjectService`

Comment: I see. Do you know if there's any other way to accomplish this? If I were to do this through every controller (JAX-RS resource), it'd be quite cumbersome. I was also trying to inject the `SecurityIdentity` object, but it also fails (I believe for the same reason as you mentioned). Thanks

Comment: That is the only standard way to do it