# How to use OIDC_CLAIM_* headers in Quarkus behind an Apache Reverse Proxy?

Tags: java, apache, openid-connect, quarkus, mod-auth-openidc

I run Quarkus behind an Apache Reverse Proxy.
The Apache use `mod_auth_openidc` to authenticate the user and pass the `OIDC_CLAIM_*` HTTP headers to the applications behind.

How to configure Quarkus to read the `OIDC_CLAIM_*` HTTP headers ? Is there a way to @Inject this in the "quarkus" way ?

Here's the relevant HTTPD configuration :

```xml
<Location /java>
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   AuthType openid-connect
   Require claim resource_access.apache-oidc.roles:admin-role

   ProxyPass "http://java-app:8080"
   ProxyPassReverse "http://java-app:8080"
</Location>
```

Actually, the only way I have found using `@HeaderParam`

```java
@GET
public String get(@HeaderParam("OIDC_CLAIM_preferred_username") String username) {
     return username;
}
```

It works but not the way it should. Can I use Quarkus to retrieve `OIDC_*` headers and access its content with the CDI ?

Thanks,

Comment: You should use a ContainerRequestFilter to manually read the headers and setup the security context and/or a RequestScoped custom bean containing the values you need. You can get inspiration from this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66695265/how-to-retrieve-securitycontext-in-a-quarkus-application